# Ember.js: Able to Add/Remove Record, But Deleted Records Still Showing

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In the Ember app I am building, one of my views is a file manager with a list of files in rows, a hasMany relationship with a user. At the end of each individual row representing a single file, I have a remove button.

When I run the App and go to the files view, it is working to populate the list with files from the API via the data store. I also have the ability to drag and drop a file into the view and it is successfully added to the data store, and the view is updated to show the new row / file.

I'm trying to add the functionality to remove a file. My problem is this: when I click to remove a file, any files that were served up by the database API will, upon a call to **.deleteRecord()**, be removed from the model / datastore, and the view will update. *However*, any files that I drop and drop in place will be removed from the data store *but not the model (still show in the array), and therefore still show in the list*.

**NOTE: I'm not yet concerned with persistence, just adding/removing from the model and view. **

Here's my code to add a file to the list (which apparently works)

```
 App.UserFilesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   sortProperties: ['name'],
   sortedFiles: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProperties'),
   actions: {
     addFile: function (fileToAdd) {
       var store = this.store;
       var newId = '1235asdf'+this.counter; //just for testing purposes!
       var thisFile = store.createRecord('file', {
         id: newId,
         name: fileToAdd.name,
         dateAdded: new Date(),
       });

       this.pushObject(thisFile);
       //*I get a valid response back from this.... *
       store.find('file', newId). then (function(result) {
         console.log('File found in the store! id: ', result.get('id'));
       });

 ... //*appears to be working...
```

Here's my code to remove a file from the list (and works for files data loaded into the store from the db):

```
    removeFile: function (file) {
      console.log('Remove the file with id: ', fileToRemove.get('id'));
      var store = this.store;
      store.find('file', fileToRemove.get('id')). then ( function (file) {
        file.deleteRecord();
        var result = file.get('isDeleted');
        console.log('File ', file.get('id'), ' removed: ', result);
      });
    },
 ... working for files from db, not files dropped in
```

When I remove a file (just dropped in), the above result for file.get('isDeleted') returns true *BUT* the file still shows in the Array behind the controller and model (via Ember Inspector) and will not visually disappear from the view.

Any help?? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, unless you're using some sort of smart collection that knows to remove a record from itself when a property changes, the store isn't going to know to remove a record from any random array.  You'll need to manually remove it in most cases.

The only Ember Data built in collections that remove deleted records are collections built with store.all and store.filter (note: store.find('type') without any parameters returns store.all). The reason they know to remove it is due to the fact that they only include non-deleted records at all time.

```
someCollection.removeOjbect(file);
```

If you're trying to commit the deleted record to the backend that only occurs after you call `save`.  If you want to do it in one fail swoop you would use `destroyRecord`.

```
file.deleteRecord();
file.save();
```

or

```
file.destroyRecord():
```

Comment: Im not trying (yet) to get the deletion to persist, simply to delete the record from the store and remove it from the model and view. Note my problem again: records in the store loaded from the database are deleting with the above code, byt records added to the view will not remove from the model and view even after apparently being deleted from the store.

Comment: Gotcha, unless you're using some sort of smart collection that knows to remove a record from itself when a property changes, the store isn't going to know to remove a record from any random array.  You'll need to manually remove it in most cases.  The only Ember Data built in collections that remove deleted records are collections built with `store.all` and `store.filter` (note: `store.find('type')` without any parameters returns `store.all`).  The reason they know to remove it is due to the fact that they only include non-deleted records at all time.

Comment: kingpin2k Thanks for the last comment. I added the code 'this.removeObject(file)' to manually remove the file object from the ArrayController. That worked. Seems odd to me, but your comments were helpful. The answer you gave above isn't the correct one for my particular question, so if you'll throw up another answer related to your last comment I'll mark it as the correct one. I could throw up my own answer and mark it, but I would not have arrived at it without your help! THanks!

Comment: Totally, I pre-pended the applicable answer.